# Calculate Date Field in SharePoint Online

Tags: date, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to calculate a due date field based on two other fields in a SharePoint Online list: [Created] and [Priority]. [Created] is auto-populated when the user creates the new list item. Easy enough. The user selects a [Priority] (Critical, High, Medium, Low). My formula always results in an error due to the pre-populated date field. Surely there's a way around this that I'm just ignorant of. It works fine in Excel, but SP pukes when I try it. TIA!

```
=IF([Priority]="Critical",[Created]+1,IF([Priority]="High",[Created]+3,IF([Priority]="Medium",[Created]+7,[Created]+14)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, it works well in my SharePoint list.

1.Create a choice column named "Priority".

2.Create a calculated column, set "The data type returned from this formula is" as "Date and Time", set "Date and Time Format" as "Date Only".

=IF([Priority]="Critical",[Created]+1,IF([Priority]="High",[Created]+3,IF([Priority]="Medium",[Created]+7,[Created]+14)))

3.Result:

[image]